# c# linq get type of item in database in tph

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, ef-code-first

I have a wpf application with a database made with Entity Framework code first.

I have a class `Shoes.cs` and two classes that inherit from shoes: `Canvas.cs` and `Boots.cs`

For mapping I've used tph method, so I have a table shoes that has a discriminator for indentifing if is canvas or boots

I have to show in datagrid all the shoes I have, with their type. I know that I can't query directly the discriminator column, so I was trying to do something like this

```
 var allShoes = (from shoes in db.Shoes
                 select shoes).ToList();

        List<string> typeOfShoes = new List<string>();

        foreach (Shoes pairShoes in allShoes)
        {
            if (pairShoes.GetType() == typeof(Canvas))
            {
                typeOfShoes .Add("Canvas");
            }
            else if (pairShoes.GetType() == typeof(Boots))
            {
                typeOfShoes .Add("Boots");
            }
            else
            {
                typeOfShoes .Add("Wrong");
            }
        }
```

I can get everything in my datagrid, but displays only "Wrong" in column type.

How can I get the type of shoes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are currently asking the class `Shoes` for its type, you should instead ask the instance for its type. In addition you should also use `is`. This operator  checks if an object is compatible with a given type, rather than relying on the exact type.

```
if (pairShoes is Canvas)
        {    
         ....
```

Comment: Your type checking also doesn't work as you are comparing to the type of the base class, I have changed my answer to use `is` instead

Comment: Thanks, it's woking now. I'm really bad in casting :)